# How can I debug a single class?

Tags: python, pyqt, pycharm, pyqt5

I'm writing a code on PyCharm, but it is easier for me if I could debugg continually while I'm writing my code. I can't figure out, that how do I get this class debugged? :

```
from PyQt5.Qt import QGraphicsPixmapItem
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap


class Level():

    def __init__(self, scene, level):
        self.scene = scene
        self.level = open(level)

    def add_item_to_scene(self):
        for x in range(self.level):
            for y in range(self.level[0]):
                if y == 'X':
                    brick = QPixmap('brick.png')
                    self.scene.addItem(brick)
```

I have just begun and this is all what I've written. I'm doing a Platformer game with PyQt5, and I'm trying to set the levels now. Thank you for any help.

Comment: What do *you* mean by "get this class debugged"? What is the code doing, and how is it different from what you expect it to be doing?

Comment: Usually I'd separate it into a different file to test it, then add it to the main code when it works. It's far easier that way

Comment: @Carl_M No, I am asking that what kind of code snippet can I write for example to the main.py -file, to be able to debug that Level() -class?

Comment: @Xantium Oh, I hadn't thought so. Sounds very sensible! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @chepner I'm learning to code with PyCharm, and this is my second programming course at uni. Therefore I'm not so good at programmin right now, and I usually do some mistakes without me noticing. So I would like to debug that class up there, so that I could see how the code progresses at any point. And I was thinking, that should I then write a code snippet to the main.py -file, or something, so that I can debug the class?

Comment: Python programming encourages certain ways of writing code, referred to as the pythonic way. A pythonic way to accomplish the objective in the question is illustrated in the answer provided.

Answer (score 0):

Use a convention to run code during development and not run the code on import as shown in the following code.

```
from PyQt5.Qt import QGraphicsPixmapItem
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap


class Level():

    def __init__(self, scene, level):
        self.scene = scene
        self.level = open(level)

    def add_item_to_scene(self):
        for x in range(self.level):
            for y in range(self.level[0]):
                if y == 'X':
                    brick = QPixmap('brick.png')
                    self.scene.addItem(brick)


# Use the following convention.
# In python the initial module run receives the name __main__.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(f'Hello my name is {__name__=} because my module was started by '
          f'pyhton. ')
    # So while developing whenever you run this module commands here will run.
    # Later on when you import the module the commands will not run.
    # because __main__ will be the name of this module
    l = Level('brick', 5)
    l.add_item_to_scene()
else:
    # Place any commands you want to run on import here.
    print(f'Hello my name is {__name__=} because my module was imported by '
          f'another module. ')
```

Demo Results:
If run directly from python

```
Hello my name is __name__='__main__' because my module was started by pyhton. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ctynd\OneDrive\CodeBase\StackOverflowActivity\OldScratches\scratch_2.py", line 27, in <module>
    l = Level('brick', 5)
  File "C:\Users\ctynd\OneDrive\CodeBase\StackOverflowActivity\OldScratches\scratch_2.py", line 9, in __init__
    self.level = open(level)
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
```

If imported:

```
import scratch_2
```

Results

```
Hello my name is __name__='scratch_2' because my module was imported by another module.
```